# Is there any callback function in Aframe <a-animation>

Tags: webvr, aframe

When I create an element of a-animation,I want to know the exact time when the animation finished.I know the "dur" or "begin" can calculate the approximate time,but is there any callback function when I use the a-animation element!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to the [`animationend` event](https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/animations.html#events) on the a-animation element. Like so:

```js
sphereAnimation.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
  sphere.setAttribute('color', '#88ff99');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane color="#EFED5E" rotation="45 0 0" scale="3 3 3" position="0 0 -3"></a-plane>
  <a-sphere id="sphere" color="#EF2D5E" position="0 0 -3">
    <a-animation 
      id="sphereAnimation" 
      attribute="position" 
      to="0 2 -3" 
      direction="alternate" 
      repeat="3" 
      easing="ease-in-out">
    </a-animation>
  </a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: <a-animation> is not working anymore in the newest versions of A-FRAME. See other answer that uses animationcomplete event.

Answer (score 1):

The 'a-animation' tag is depricated in favour of animation="". You need to attach the event handler for the animationcomplete event to the object which is being animated. Here's what worked for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function sphereEventListener(){
            aSphere.addEventListener('animationcomplete', function(){
                console.log("Do something interesting here...");
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="sphereEventListener()">
    <a-scene>
        <a-sphere
            animation="dur: 1000; property: position; to: 5 0 -10"
            id="aSphere"
            position="-5 0 -10"
        >
        </a-sphere>
        <a-sky color="black"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```